# How to create a 2d procedural spline based road with 2 edge colliders?

Tags: unity, procedural-generation, splines

I am trying to make a top down 2d spline-based road that is procedurally generated and endless. The aim is that the player starts inside the road and has to navigate the road and if he touches any of its edges he "dies" and the game reloads. I have looked at various resources online for help but can't seem to find the answer. I have tried using the Path creator tool (by sebastian lague) and followed his YouTube series and I have even tried to use Unity's 2d sprite shape asset. The issue is, with the Path creator tool, I am able to create the road procedurally, but I can't figure out how to add multiple edge colliders on its boundaries. The same issue is there for Unity's sprite shape asset except with that, I don't know how to generate the road also (procedurally) and I can't find any tutorial or resource that explains how to do so.
Can someone explain an easy way to achieve this (also, it has to be procedurally since my goal is to make it endless)?

Comment: Cant you create a few spline roads manually and join them together to get the endless effect?

Comment: Yes that is not the issue. The issue is assigning 2 edge colliders to it via code and align them to each edge of the road

Comment: If you create a segment of the road, of course you can already add the edge collider at that time. And it is endless as well, you just instantiate a new segment each time you travelled a certain distance. The player won't notice it and you have more options in your road creation as well.

Comment: @Zibelas the problem isn't adding just an edge collider. The problem is, I need 2 edge colliders, both on the EDGE of the road, not in the middle.

Comment: So add 2 of them? Where exactly are you having the trouble with. Any collider will do as well, they don't need to be necessary an edge collider.